# Array as a condition for find_or_create_by in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have something like this:

```
types = ['landline', 'cell']
Phone.find_or_create_by(person_id: 1, type: types) do |record|
 record.number = '0'
end
```

This doesn't work. New records don't get created. But when I rewrite it to look like this:

```
types = ['landline', 'cell']
types.each do |type|
 Phone.find_or_create_by(person_id: 1, type: type) do |record|
  record.number = '0'
 end
end
```

it works.

Any ideas why `find_or_create_by` doesn't work with array as a condition?

Comment: Do you want to create 1 new object of the Phone class or 2 new objects?  `find_or_create_by` is specifically for 1 object and 1 object only.

Comment: I would like to create 2 new objects. Is there something similar to `find_or_create_by` that would create 2 new objects?

Comment: No.  You either use the iterator in the second code block as shown, or you move that logic to a custom method if you're going to call it in several different places.

Comment: Can you describe the problem in a simple user story? For example "A user should be able to create his account with multiple phone numbers ...".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nice question, here is my explanation with an example.

`find_or_create_by` first runs a `select query` and then proceeds for the `create method`

There is a note in the api documentation of find_or_create_by,

**Please note *this method is not atomic*, it runs first a SELECT, and if there are no results an INSERT is attempted. If there are other threads or processes there is a race condition between both calls and it could be the case that you end up with two similar records.**

[Here is the reference of find_or_create_by](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by)

so, when this command is ran, it will first runs a **select query**.

**For example, let me take a user table and show you with that table from console result.**

I have a user with email `test222@example.com` in the database but not, `test333@example.com`.

`User.find_or_create_by(email: ['test222@example.com','test333@example.com'])`

now when I run the `find_or_create_by` this is the query generated.

`User Load (175.5ms)  SELECT`users`.* FROM`users`WHERE`users`.`email`IN ('test222@example.com', 'test333@example.com') LIMIT 1`

The response is,

`=> #<User id: 82, provider: "email", uid: "test222@example.com", name: nil, nickname: nil, image: nil, email: "test222@example.com", created_at: "2016-09-05 12:35:01", updated_at: "2016-09-05 12:35:01">`

**So it returned the found user and didn't run the create method, ignoring the not found(second email)**

Now, if I run it in a loop,

```
emails = ['test222@example.com','test333@example.com']
emails.each do |email|
    User.find_or_create_by(email: email)
end
```

**The INSERT query will be ran for the second email,**

```
**INSERT INTO `users` (`email`,`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('test@ead.com', '2016-10-07 13:16:25', '2016-10-07 13:16:25')**
```

This is the same case in your's too.